# ActiveMQ maven plugin configuration

Tags: spring, maven, activemq-classic

I have a problem with using ActiveMQ in a Spring project.
I am trying to integrate the ActiveMQ maven plugin into my project to use it in integration tests.
Here my configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
(the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
--> <!-- START SNIPPET: example --> <beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
xmlns:cam ="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
xmlns:jetty ="http://mortbay.com/schemas/jetty/1.0"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring 
http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core 
http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.5.0.xsd
http://mortbay.com/schemas/jetty/1.0
http://jetty.mortbay.org/jetty.xsd"> <!-- this location for the schema doesn't work, I dont know exactly where the schema is located
xmlns:jetty ="http://mortbay.com/schemas/jetty/1.0"
http://mortbay.com/schemas/jetty/1.0
http://jetty.mortbay.org/jetty.xsd   -->

<!-- Allows us to use system properties as variables in this configuration file -->
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
     <property name="locations">
        <value>file:///${activemq.base}/conf/credentials.properties</value>
     </property>      
</bean>

<amq:broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.base}/data">

    <!-- Destination specific policies using destination names or wildcards -->
    <destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
            <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry queue=">" memoryLimit="5mb"/>
                <policyEntry topic=">" memoryLimit="5mb">
                  <!-- you can add other policies too such as these
                    <dispatchPolicy>
                        <strictOrderDispatchPolicy/>
                    </dispatchPolicy>
                    <subscriptionRecoveryPolicy>
                        <lastImageSubscriptionRecoveryPolicy/>
                    </subscriptionRecoveryPolicy>
                  -->
                </policyEntry>
            </policyEntries>
        </policyMap>
    </destinationPolicy>

    <!-- Use the following to configure how ActiveMQ is exposed in JMX -->
    <managementContext>
        <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
    </managementContext>

    <!-- The store and forward broker networks ActiveMQ will listen to -->
    <networkConnectors>
        <!-- by default just auto discover the other brokers -->
        <networkConnector name="default-nc" uri="multicast://default"/>
        <!-- Example of a static configuration:
        <networkConnector name="host1 and host2" uri="static://(tcp://host1:61616,tcp://host2:61616)"/>
        -->
    </networkConnectors>

    <persistenceAdapter>
        <amqPersistenceAdapter syncOnWrite="false" directory="${activemq.base}/data" maxFileLength="20 mb"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>

    <!-- Use the following if you wish to configure the journal with JDBC -->
    <!--
    <persistenceAdapter>
        <journaledJDBC dataDirectory="${activemq.base}/data" dataSource="#postgres-ds"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>
    -->

    <!-- Or if you want to use pure JDBC without a journal -->
    <!--
    <persistenceAdapter>
        <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataSource="#postgres-ds"/>
    </persistenceAdapter>
    -->

    <sslContext>
        <sslContext keyStore="file:${activemq.base}/conf/broker.ks" keyStorePassword="password" trustStore="file:${activemq.base}/conf/broker.ts" trustStorePassword="password"/>
    </sslContext>

    <!--  The maximum about of space the broker will use before slowing down producers -->
    <systemUsage>
        <systemUsage>
            <memoryUsage>
                <memoryUsage limit="20 mb"/>
            </memoryUsage>
            <storeUsage>
                <storeUsage limit="1 gb" name="foo"/>
            </storeUsage>
            <tempUsage>
                <tempUsage limit="100 mb"/>
            </tempUsage>
        </systemUsage>
    </systemUsage>


    <!-- The transport connectors ActiveMQ will listen to -->
    <transportConnectors>
        <!--<transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://localhost:61616" discoveryUri="multicast://default"/>-->
        <!--<transportConnector name="default-nc" uri="multicast://default"/>-->
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://localhost:61616" />
        <transportConnector name="ssl" uri="ssl://localhost:61617"/>
        <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://localhost:61613"/>
        <transportConnector name="xmpp" uri="xmpp://localhost:61222"/>
    </transportConnectors>

</amq:broker>

<!--
** Lets deploy some Enterprise Integration Patterns inside the ActiveMQ Message Broker
** For more details see
**
** http://activemq.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html
-->
<cam:camelContext id="camel">

    <!-- You can use a <package> element for each root package to search for Java routes -->
    <cam:package>org.foo.bar</cam:package>

    <!-- You can use Spring XML syntax to define the routes here using the <route> element -->
    <cam:route>
        <cam:from uri="activemq:example.A"/>
        <cam:to uri="activemq:example.B"/>
    </cam:route>
</cam:camelContext>

<!--
** Lets configure some Camel endpoints
**
** http://activemq.apache.org/camel/components.html
-->

<!-- configure the camel activemq component to use the current broker -->
<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent" >
    <property name="connectionFactory">
      <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
        <property name="brokerURL" value="vm://localhost?create=false&amp;waitForStart=10000" />
        <property name="userName" value="${activemq.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${activemq.password}"/>
      </bean>
    </property>
</bean>



<!-- Uncomment to create a command agent to respond to message based admin commands on the ActiveMQ.Agent topic -->
<!--
<commandAgent xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerUrl="vm://localhost" username="${activemq.username}" password="${activemq.password}"/>
-->


<!-- An embedded servlet engine for serving up the Admin console -->
<jetty:jetty>
    <connectors>
        <nioConnector port="8161"/>
    </connectors>

    <handlers>
        <webAppContext contextPath="/admin" resourceBase="${activemq.base}/webapps/admin" logUrlOnStart="true"/>
        <webAppContext contextPath="/demo" resourceBase="${activemq.base}/webapps/demo" logUrlOnStart="true"/>
        <webAppContext contextPath="/fileserver" resourceBase="${activemq.base}/webapps/fileserver" logUrlOnStart="true"/>
    </handlers>
</jetty:jetty>
<!--  This xbean configuration file supports all the standard spring xml configuration options -->

</beans>
```

The problem I have is using the jetty Namespace.
The schema cannot be found and downloaded: http://jetty.mortbay.org/jetty.xsd 
Here a link from Apache ActiveMQ:
http://activemq.apache.org/complex-single-broker-configuration-stomp-only.html

There is not specified any location for this schema.
The ActiveMQ starts without having the schema location but if I use a schema validator like in Eclipse it tells me that I have an error in the file and the schema location cannot be found.

Any idea where I can find the schema for the jetty element ?

Comment: also the jetty project has moved to a eclipse project. Are the xsd's hosted from there.

Comment: The question is where is located the new schema, I suppose in a new location but can you specify me the new location ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I have the jetty-xbean into my dependencies, but this is not relevant for the xml validation or is this library including the schemas ?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem too and I lost a whole hour to find a solution.

Essentially [the example in the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/complex-single-broker-configuration-stomp-only.html) is outdated.

The dependencies required to enable jetty with activemq-maven-plugin are as follows:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-xbean</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.25</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-all-server</artifactId>
    <version>7.6.7.v20120910</version>
</dependency>
```

Following is the complete configuration of the activemq-maven-plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq.tooling</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <configUri>${configUri}</configUri>
        <fork>false</fork>
        <systemProperties>
            <property>
                <name>javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword</name>
                <value>password</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>org.apache.activemq.default.directory.prefix</name>
                <value>./target/</value>
            </property>
        </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-spring</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-xbean</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.25</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                     <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
         </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-all-server</artifactId>
            <version>7.6.7.v20120910</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>activemq-leveldb-store</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-activemq</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Then to enable jetty is enough to import the jetty configuration file into the activemq the configuration file.

The following snippet is taken from the file ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/activemq.xml in the ActiveMQ latest release at the time of this writing (5.8.0):

```
<beans
          xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:amq="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd">

    <!--
        The <broker> element is used to configure the ActiveMQ broker.
    -->
    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">

       ...

    </broker>

    <!--
        Enable web consoles, REST and Ajax APIs and demos

        Take a look at ${ACTIVEMQ_HOME}/conf/jetty.xml for more details
    -->
    <import resource="jetty.xml"/>

</beans>
```

Cheers,

Domenico

Comment: This seems pretty helpful Domenico, thanks. Do we need to place a jetty.xml file or it is downloaded along with the dependencies?

Comment: This does not seem to start up the console for me in jetty. Have things changed again? If so, can anybody provide an update please? I am trying ports 8161 and 8162?

Comment: This doesn't work for me. jetty-xbean will pull in Jetty 6 and jetty-all-server will pull in Jetty 7, so you will have *two* Jetty implementations on the classpath.